# SPARQL-Query for all objects with a specific prefix?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, topbraid-composer

I created an ontology with different prefixes (rdf, rdfs, owl, example, car, bike, ...). I use them to demarcate different domains and examples.

How can I query for all objects with the profix i.e. "car"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the future, providing a minimal sample of the data will help in providing a working query on the data. With no further detailsand assuming that you mean by "objects" the objects of triples (and indeed untested) :

```sql
PREFIX car: <TODO_ADD_URI_OF_NAMESPACE_HERE>
SELECT * {
 ?s ?p ?o .
 FILTER(isUri(?o) && STRSTARTS(STR(?o), STR(car:)))
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. This version would work too:
PREFIX car: <http....>
SELECT * {
 ?s ?p ?o .
 FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?o), STR(car:)))
}